# Find indices of rows that x fall into in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, search

I have a numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
stm = np.array([[0,1],[1,5],[4,5],[3,6],[7,9]]) 
x = 3.5
```

I want to find list of indices where: `stm[i][0]<= x <=stm[i][1]`
and the result should be `[1,3]`.

Is there any way to do this in numpy without having to loop through `stm`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use boolean masking and `np.where()`:

```
>>> np.where((stm[:,0] <= x) & (stm[:,1] >= x))
(array([1, 3]),)
```

As an alternative you could have also used `np.argwhere` (as suggested by @MSeifert), `np.nonzero` or `np.flatnonzero`.
They all behave slightly differently, so it's a good idea to know about all of them.

Comment: Changed to `np.argwhere` instead (as proposed by @MSeifert) since I think it's the better choice here.

Comment: I think using `argwhere` is better since it can only ever provide an index, and not the value itself, like `where` does. It gives the same result as long as you don't give the (optional) `x,y` arguments to `where` though.

Comment: I had already upvoted yours (and we wrote the answers at the same time). But you are right, I could add more options to my answer to make it stand out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133374/discussion-between-hannes-ovren-and-mseifert).

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved using boolean masks and [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
>>> np.argwhere((stm[:,0] <= x) & (stm[:,1] >= x))
array([[1],
       [3]], dtype=int64)
```

or if you want just the first index:

```
>>> np.argwhere((stm[:,0] <= x) & (stm[:,1] >= x))[:,0]
array([1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit shorter :

```
((stm-x).prod(1)<=0).nonzero()
```